# pymongo query that matches values from fields within the same document?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am accessing MongoDB with pymongo and a document looks like this:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('60f1803de8984dc1414687a4'),
'match': {'season': '1',
       'node': {'id': 17, 'name': 'zxc'},
       'players': [{'userId': 'asdf',
                     'field1': 'asd',
                    'pings': [{'currentPing': 8,
                                'nodeId': 43},
                              {'currentPing': 8,
                                'nodeId': 29},
                              {'currentPing': 22,
                                  'nodeId': 17}],
                   {'userId': 'fdsa',
                     'field1': 'asd',
                    'pings': [{'currentPing': 10,
                                'nodeId': 43},
                              {'currentPing': 50,
                                'nodeId': 29},
                              {'currentPing': 10,
                                  'nodeId': 17}]}
```

I want to get the nodeId field that equals the node.id field, so far my request looks like this:

```
db_collection.find_one({"$and": [{"match.season": {"$eq" : 1}},  {"match.players":{"$exists": True}}]}, {'match.node.id': 1, 'match.players.ping': 1})
```

but I'm unsure how to query by the described condition

Comment: This question would probably be easier to answer if that was a complete and valid document and if you would show the output you're trying to get.

Comment: Hello Henry, this might not be the complete document but I think it is enough as an example. As far validity is concerned, you are right there is a '}' missing at the end; but I think the rest are fine. The find_one command I posted above, requests the complete fields of match.node.id and match.players.ping, but I would like to request only those match.players.pings whose nodeId matches match.node.id per document. For example, based on the above, I would like to receive only the match.players.pings where match.players.pings.nodeId is 17